# R: Function to return the category that has the maximum in another variable

Tags: r

[image: Screenshot of sample data]

Is there a nice simple function to return which diet has the highest average? I can calculate the means from each diet using:

```
mean(filter(data, grepl('Chow', diet))$Ileibacterium)
mean(filter(data, grepl('HFD', diet))$Ileibacterium)
mean(filter(data, grepl('HFHSD', diet))$Ileibacterium)
mean(filter(data, grepl('HSD', diet))$Ileibacterium)
```

and then figure out which is the highest from reading the output, however this is a lengthy process. I can use the max(...) function however this will return the maximum mean value and not which diet has the maximum. Is there some sort of function where I can put all 4 of these as inputs and it will return the diet that has the maximum mean in the Ileibacterium variable?

Comment: Could you provide the data shown in your screenshot please? Or an example data for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @Droplet any dataset works. Can use mtcars for example. Is there a function that calculates what categorical grouping has the highest mean in another variable.

Comment: This looks off-topic for CR@SE: The code presented/referred does not [work as intended](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (yet). See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a categorical variable and want to find the category value that achieves the highest mean value for another variable.

R has many simple ways to get the average of some variable, grouped by a different variable. In base R you might do

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, mean)
#        3        4        5 
# 16.10667 24.53333 21.38000
```

while in tidyverse it might be something like

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarize(meanmpg=mean(mpg))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#    gear meanmpg
#   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     3    16.1
# 2     4    24.5
# 3     5    21.4
```

In either case, you have an object with one value for each group, and all that remains is extracting the categorical variable level associated with the highest value:

```
names(tail(sort(tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, mean)), 1))
# [1] "4"

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarize(meanmpg=mean(mpg)) %>%
  arrange(meanmpg) %>%
  tail(1) %>%
  select(gear)
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
#    gear
#   <dbl>
# 1     4
```